# Python Logger module with a class and rotating log handling

Tags: python, logging

I was creating a set of .py files into a 'package' that I wanted all to import a standardized 'logger' that would allow all modules to log to a single file.

```
class BaseLogger():
def __init__(self, module_name, specific_task_name):
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="app." + specific_task_name + "." + module_name + ".log",
        format="%(levelname)-10s;%(asctime)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;%(message)s;%(thread)s;%(threadName)s",
        #level=logging.DEBUG
    )
    self.baselogger = logging.getLogger("app." + module_name + "." + specific_task_name )
    self.baselogger.setLevel('DEBUG')
```

So the idea is that all my .py files, import BaseLogger and instantiate that object and it'll find a current logger by same name, therefore LOG to one file...

Problem is i'm now trying to create a rotating log structure and just lost... I've added to .basicConfig [failed to iterable], I'm thinking I should do a self.baselogger.addHandler .. but that makes the log file go empty....

How can I create a rotating log file with my above 'classed' implementation... or have I been doing it wrong?...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a class wrapper as logging module is pretty awesome by design. What you need to do is to register/get a logger and configure it with a format and file handler.

Here is an example with a wrapper:

```
class BaseLogger(object):

    def __init__(self, module_name, specific_task_name):
        filename = "app." + specific_task_name + "." + module_name + ".log",
        format = ("%(levelname)-10s;%(asctime)s;%(module)s;%(funcName)s;"
                  "%(message)s;%(thread)s;%(threadName)s"),
        # you do not have to keep the reference
        # it is possible to get logger from anywhere using getLogger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(specific_task_name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # make sure to add RotatingFileHandler only once
        # you might need to update condition if you have more than 1 handler
        if not self.logger.handlers:
            fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename,
                                              mode='a',
                                              maxBytes=MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE,
                                              backupCount=2,
                                              encoding=None,
                                              delay=0)
            fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(format)
            fh.setFormatter(formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(fh)
```

I would drop a class and go with a `fabric` function:

```
def get_logger(name):
    # setup new logger here if it does not exist 
    # return instance if it is there
    pass
```

Comment: thank you for helping out... so at the moment, I use a 'main.py' file to run and has imports from 3-5 module files and threads out.... If my main.py creates a 'log' how do all the other modules know to log to the same file in main.py? i think thats why i thought i needed a Class wrapper for this.

Comment: you always can get the same logger by its name from anywhere: `logging.getLogger(specific_task_name)`. The point here is to setup a file handler and then you can use logging as it is

Comment: dam so the class thing worked with a few removals of commas but i'm swapping over to the specific_task_name logger getting... thanks so much!!! took me a while to get it wrapped in my head lol